# Go Ethereum (GETH) Node Error

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I'm trying to get smarter on blockchain broadly so downloaded Bitcoin Core / Geth nodes recently and got them both working but admittedly I hardly know what I'm doing. I didn't realize that I needed to shutdown geth in a particular way (as opposed to just exiting out of CMD), so I did an unclean shutdown and then received an error that keeps repeating directly after that. The error is 'Section processing failed, type=bloombits, error ="canonical block #12597521"'. Searching around I've seen this error occur to others that improperly closed geth, but I've failed to find a fix and if it actually makes an impact to my node. My chain is still up to date.

Would appreciate any advice/insight to this error.

Thanks!

[image: Unclean Shutdown and First Error]

[image: Error continuously has occurred after this point]

Answer (score 0):

In go-ethereum repo there are a couple of related issues. In [issue #22471](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/22471#issuecomment-795585721) Ligi suggest a couple of solutions

- Try PR [#21650](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/21650)
- Sync from scratch